# Electric field in a center of a tiny hole cut out in a hollow sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

> Suppose we have a hollow sphere charged uniformly with
> a surface charge density σ. A circular hole is cut out,
> small compared to the radius R of the sphere. Find the electric field
> in the center of this hole.

[image]

My idea is to present the electric field in the center of a hole as a superposition of an electric field from the whole sphere with surface charge density $\sigma$ and a disk (as the hole area is very small) with surface charge density $-\sigma$. However, I don't know if it's possible to find electric field on the surface of a sphere (it's probably even not defined there) as it has a kind of jump at this line (the thickness of the surface is zero).
Here is an e-field for sphere:
$E(r)=\begin{cases} 0,\ r < R\\ {\sigma R^2\over{\varepsilon_0 r^2}}, \ r > R\end{cases}$

So can I just treat the e-field on the surface as $E(R)={\sigma\over{\varepsilon_0}}$ or it is not defined on the surface and there is a better solution for the problem?

Comment: Have some fun -- read Jackson.  Or consider the limit of  R--> $\infty$ , a hole in a conducting plane.   :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, could you explain if I can use the ideas described in my problem presentation? It's actually intriguing that if we treat the e-field on the surface as $E(R)={\sigma\over{\varepsilon_0}}$, and the e-field in the center of the disk is ${-\sigma\over{2\varepsilon_0}}$, then the resulting superposition is $E={\sigma\over{\varepsilon_0}} - {\sigma\over{2\varepsilon_0}}={\sigma\over{2\varepsilon_0}}$ and that is the correct answer...

Answer (score 3):

That is an old 'trick' question with no calculation needed.  With the small disk in place, the field just outside is $E_0$, and the field just inside is 0.  If you move from just inside the sphere to just outside, the field due to the disk changes sign, but the field due to the rest of the sphere doesn't. Therefore, the field due to the disk has the same magnitude as the field due to the rest of the sphere, and removing the sphere leaves a field $E_0/2$ inside the hole.

Comment: I just can't understand how the change/not_change of sign means that "the field due to the disk has the same magnitude as the field due to the rest of the sphere"

Comment: Draw a picture showing arrows for the $\bf E$ vectors from both sides of the disk, and the $\bf E$ vector inside and outside the sphere.